# Android studio or Eclipse as IDE for Android Development?

Tags: android

I wanna know which ADT bundle and IDE is preferly use by developers and why?
So i can deside which one is suitable for me to be update.

Comment: Android Studio is the official IDE: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

Comment: Android Studio is better option if you would only be developing android apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio is the official IDE for Android Development. It is the only tool into which Google will be putting development resources.

The Eclipse ADT plugin is effectively now deprecated and will no longer receive development effort from Google.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is best all the developers moving on android studio and also use the gradle build system because gradle is a advance building tools and also android studio provide a very good environment for development. Please let me know if you have any doubt.